# Confusion with this complex looking nested list

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension

I have the following code that I am using to return a nested set of lists:

```
url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/stagestatfeed/9155/stageteams/'
                    url = str(''.join(url[0:3]))
                    params = {
            'against': '0',            
            'field': '0',
            'teamId': '-1',
            'type': '8'
            }

                    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

                    responser = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

                    responser = json.loads(responser.text.replace("'", '"').decode('cp1252'))
```

Previously I would have cheated at this point and just removed all the brackets from `responser.text`, however I want to try and use a list comprehension instead against the item returned by `json.loads()`. Instead of having responser returning as:

```
    [[[13, u'Arsenal', [[[[u'goal', u'corner', u'rightfoot', [1]], [u'goal', u'crossedfreekick', 
    u'header', [1]], [u'goal', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [3]], [u'miss', u'corner', u'header', [2]], 
    [u'miss', u'corner', u'leftfoot', [1]], [u'miss', u'corner', u'rightfoot', [1]], [u'miss', 
    u'crossedfreekick', u'header', [1]], [u'miss', u'crossedfreekick', u'leftfoot', [2]], [u'miss', 
    u'directfreekick', u'rightfoot', [1]], [u'miss', u'fastbreak', u'rightfoot', [1]], [u'miss', 
    u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [12]], [u'miss', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [19]]]]]], [14, u'Leicester', 
    [[[[u'goal', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [1]], [u'miss', u'crossedfreekick', u'header', [1]], 
[u'miss', u'crossedfreekick', u'rightfoot', [2]], [u'miss', u'fastbreak', u'rightfoot', [1]], 
[u'miss', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [7]], [u'miss', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [9]]]]]]
    ....
    ....
    ....
 [171, u'Queens Park Rangers', [[[[u'goal', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [1]], [u'miss', u'corner', 
u'header', [5]], [u'miss', u'crossedfreekick', u'header', [1]], [u'miss', u'directfreekick', 
u'rightfoot', [2]], [u'miss', u'openplay', u'header', [1]], [u'miss', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [4]],
 [u'miss', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [23]], [u'miss', u'throwin', u'header', [1]]]]]]]]
```

...which is just a series of nested lists from source, I have tried to use a selective list comprehension to extract certain values from the nested lists:

```
goal1 = {"'goal','openplay','leftfoot'", "'goal','openplay','rightfoot'", "'goal','openplay','header'", "'goal','openplay','otherbodypart'"}
                    responser1 = sum(int(value) for key, value in responser if key in goal1)

print responser1
```

What I want is to do this selective comprehension by every football team in the nested list. So for example my output might look like:

```
arsenal,5,3,1,1
liverpool,4,1,0
...
...
...
hull,5,3,1,2
burnley,2,1,1,0
```

When I run this code however, I get the following error:

```
regex1 = sum(int(value) for key, value in regex if key in goal1)
    exceptions.ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

...which I dont know how to resolve. Can anyone suggest a syntax for me that will transform my source data into my desired final output?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your current code. They mostly stem from the fact that `responser` is deeply nested and you're trying to iterate on it only at the top level. You'll need to do some additional processing to see the goal events that you're looking for.

One approach might be to write a bunch of nested loops. I don't understand your data well enough to guess what each level of nesting means, but you could do something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# do html request and json parsing to get `responser`

results = defaultdict(int)
for match in responser: 
    for num_events, team, events in match:
         for x in events: # no idea what this level means
             for y in x: # nor this one
                 for event_type, play_type, body_part, something_else in y:
                     if event_type == "goal" and play_type == "openplay":
                         results[event_type, play_type] += 1
```

You can use the values from the intermediate loops as necessary (e.g. including the team name in the data somehow). It's not clear what exactly the numbers in your desired output mean, so I can't give exact code.